# PHP ftp_put create file but doesn't move

Tags: php

I'm trying to send a file via FTP connection from one server to another. I'm able to create the connection and send the file to the folder I want.

The file is created, but it has 0bytes. Also, the php function fails after some time with this error message:

> Connection timed out

I also changed the permissions on the folder on the server receiving the file, it has public `read`, `write` and `execute` permissions, however, when the new file arrives on the server, it doesn't have the default permission, but only `read`.

What I might be doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
$localFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/'.$file;
$moveFile  = '/public_html/images/'.$file;

$ftp_server   = 'ftp.mywebsite.com';
$ftp_username = 'xxxxxx';
$ftp_password = 'xxxxxx';

$ftp_connection = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$ftp_login      = ftp_login($ftp_connection, $ftp_username, $ftp_password);

if ( ftp_put($ftp_connection, $moveFile, $localFile, FTP_ASCII) ) {
    print_r('Completed');
} else {
    print_r('Error');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same kind of issue and solved by setting `ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);` just after ftp login- my code is like below-

```
$ssl_connection_id = ftp_ssl_connect(FTP_HOST);
if($ssl_connection_id) 
{
  $login = ftp_login($ssl_connection_id,FTP_USERNAME, FTP_PASSWORD);
  ftp_pasv($ssl_connection_id, true);
  if($login)
  {
     if (ftp_put($ssl_connection_id,FTP_PATH.$filename, $localFile, FTP_ASCII)) 
     {
         echo "successfully uploaded \n";

     } 
   }
}
```

thats all, another difference is that, i use make use of IP address instead of url(ftp.mywebsite.com) like 5.xx.xx.xxx

Comment: let me know whether it is helpful or not

Comment: Yes! It worked. One thing I had to change.. `FTP_ASCII` wasn't working, when I changed to `FTP_BINARY` then it worked 100%. Any idea why it happened? Btw, on this test, I was uploading images.

Comment: FTP_ASCII may occur error other than text files(html,css) when OS difference between two servers, but FTP_BINARY works fine for non text files (images,videos)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help! =D